# UIImagePickerController allowsEditing Layout

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, ios11, iphone-x, presentviewcontroller

I'm presenting a UIImagePickerController with the allowsEditing enabled. I feel that the UIImagePickerController is not displayed correctly. The Safe **Area Layout Guide** does not seems to be respected.

[image: UIImagePickerController Editing mode]

As you can see there are few problems with the layout. First the Image is not **centered** in the middle of the square. Secondly, the **Bottom Ba**r doesn't respect the **Safe Layout Guide**. Shouldn't be that close to the *Home indicator*.
I can not drag the image to the complete top edge, stay above. And the contrary with the bottom edge.

I feel that the layout has just moved to the bottom.
If you didn't notice, I'm using an iPhone X.

Here is the code where I present this viewController.

```
presentingController.present(imagePickerController, animated: true)
```

the source type of the **imagePickerController** is .PhotoLibrary

```
imagePickerController.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
```

And my *imagePickerController* is just a child of **UIImagePickerController**.

Where I just enabled the **allowsEditing** to true in *viewDidLoad*.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I am having the same problem.

Comment: unfortunately @SAHM first, I don't really remember, and secondly, I don't think I found the solution :/